# REAL HOMES THEME problem array_filter, bool given

Tags: php, arrays, wordpress, filter, themes

Morning!

First of all, excuse my rusty english. I have an issue with a wordpress theme. To be more especific with the search form:

> Warning: array_filter() expects parameter 1 to be array, bool given in
> /home/inmobil1/public_html/wp-content/themes/realhomes/assets/modern/partials/properties/search/advance.php
> on line 45

I tried to contact theme suport, but they are getting delayed to troubleshoot it.

I also tried to deactivated all the plugins, one by one, and doesnt't work. So I think the problem must be in the code:

```
 <div class="inspiry_show_on_doc_ready rh_prop_search rh_prop_search_init <?php echo esc_attr($advance_search_expand);?>">
     <?php
     if ( inspiry_is_rvr_enabled() ) {
         get_template_part( 'assets/modern/partials/properties/search/rvr-form' );
     } else {
         if ( array_filter( $get_theme_search_fields ) ) {
             switch ( $get_search_form_layout ) {
                 case 'default';
                     get_template_part( 'assets/modern/partials/properties/search/form' );
                     break;
                 case 'smart';
                     get_template_part( 'assets/modern/partials/properties/search/form-smart' );
                     break;
             }
         }
     }

     ?>
 </div>
 <!-- /.rh_prop_search -->
 <?php
   endif;
  }
?>
```

Could anyone, please help me out to sort this?

Comment: as the error say `Warning: array_filter() expects parameter 1 to be array, bool given in`, you give `array_filter()` with boolean value try debug your `$get_theme_search_fields`.

Comment: Thank you Mr. Sherlock, unfortunately, I do not know how to debug $get_theme_search_fields. Could you help me out please?